# Make realm gradle plugin work with android studio 3

Tags: java, android, gradle, realm

I recently updated my android studio to take advantage of the new features announced at I/O 17. Unfortunately the realm plugin isn't compatible with the new android build tools.

I really want to use the new features in my new project.

If anyone here managed to get it work with the new android studio 3, Kindly help me with how you did that. Thanks in advance

Comment: They are working on it see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/4663 but you can use Retrolambda with build tools 2 for the next... 3-4 weeks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now. I went to the Realm website, and re-read the installation instructions and by ensuring the following line was in the build.gradle file, it worked perfectly:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1"
```

Hope this helps!